# Implementing Heap Sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am attempting to implement Heap sort in my program to learn more about sorting algorithms. However I am running in to an issue.

I call Heap sort in main like this:

**Main:**

```
heap_sort(h_vector);
```

Where h_vector is a randomly sized vector with random ordered elements. My heap sort algorithm looks like.

**Heap Sort:**

```
void max_heapify(std::vector<int>& v, int i)
{
    int left = i + 1, right = i + 2;
    int largest;

    if( left <= v.size() && v[left] > v[i])
    {
        largest = left;
    }

    else
    {
        largest = i;
    }

    if( right <= v.size() && v[right] > v[largest])
    {
        largest = right;
    }

    if( largest != i)
    {
        std::swap(v[i], v[largest]);
        max_heapify(v,largest);
    }



}

void build_max_heap(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for( int i = v.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        max_heapify(v, i);
    }

}

void heap_sort(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    build_max_heap(v);
    int x = 0;
    int i = v.size() - 1;
    while( i > x)
    {
        std::swap(v[i],v[x]);
        ++x;
        --i;
    }

}
```

Whenever I add this sort to my program I get the following error.

**Error:**

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x096c82d0 ***
```

I am not sure what could be causing this. I thought at first that my alogrithm might be going out of bounds of the vector but I have checked a few times and I do not see where. Any ideas? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you suspect it's going out of bounds, you can replace all `v[i]` calls with `v.at(i)`. That will throw an exception when `i` is OOB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the very first invokation of `max_heapify()`, you invoke it with `i = v.size() - 2`

Thus, when you set `right = i + 2;` you actually set: `right = v.size()`

Now, look at this:

```
 if( right <= v.size() && v[right] > v[largest])
```

Note that `right <= v.size()`, and you are now trying to access `v[right]`, which is out of bound.

Note that the last index of `v` is `v[v.size() -1]` - so all your if statements should be `right < v.size()` [instead `<=`]

I assume solving these issues will solve your bug eventually.

Comment: That is what I needed. It is the little subtleties of vectors I am trying to learn. Made the two to changes you suggested above and it fixed my issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your "for" loop in build_max_heap() is running backwards. You can't build a heap that way. You start with the first element of the array as a heap and then add subsequent elements to it. This does not work starting from the end, because the rest of the array is not a heap yet.

Also, what amit said.

In particular, a heap will be defined by the array and the size of the heap - not the array because it's not always ALL part of the heap. So you're missing a parameter (the heap size). The only time the whole array is a heap, is after build_max_heap() is done and before you run the second pass to pull it into sorted order. At every other time, the heap size is not the array size.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted this heap sort solution, refer this.
Python implementation of the heap sort algorithm:

def heapify(aiml, n, i):
largest = i
l = 2 * i + 1
r = 2 * i + 2

```
if l < n and aiml[l] > aiml[largest]:
    largest = l

if r < n and aiml[r] > aiml[largest]:
    largest = r

if largest != i:
    aiml[i], aiml[largest] = aiml[largest], aiml[i]
    heapify(aiml, n, largest)
```

def heapSort(aiml):
n = len(aiml)

```
# Build a maxheap.
for i in range(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
    heapify(aiml, n, i)

# One by one extract elements
for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
    aiml[i], aiml[0] = aiml[0], aiml[i]  # swap
    heapify(aiml, i, 0)
```

## Example usage:

aiml = [12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7]
heapSort(aiml)
print("Sorted array is", aiml)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int a[90],n;

void swap(int *a,int *b)
 {
   int temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
 }
void ct_heap(int n)
{
 int j,data,i;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
  data=a[i];
   for(j=i;j>0;j--)
   {
    if(a[(i-1)/2]<data)
     {
       swap(&a[(i-1)/2],&a[i]);
       i=(i-1)/2;
     }
   }
 }
}
void display()
{
  int k;
   for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
     printf("%d\t",a[k]);
    }
   printf("\n");
 }
void heap_sort()
{
ct_heap(n);
int end;
end=n-1;

while(end>=0)
  {
    swap(&a[end],&a[0]);

    ct_heap(end);
    end=end-1;
  }
}
int main()
{
    int i;

      printf("Enter Number of Nodes\n");
      scanf("%d",&n);
      printf("Enter Data\n");
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      scanf("%d",&a[i]);
      printf("After Heap Creation\n");
      ct_heap(n);
      display();
      heap_sort();
      printf("Array After Heap Sort\n");
      display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is easy to Understand. If any one have any query regarding any of the algo please inbox me